# Mac user Authorization with finder (icon replacement)

Tags: macos, icons, desktop, finder

I'm trying to understand the mechanics behind user authorization in MacOS. I would like to replace a 3rd party app icon (app/resources/icon.icns) programmatically, TBH changing icons after actualizations, by hand, is driving me crazy.

When I do it manually there's a user pass requirement. I've written a similar script for Windows, but I'm kinda new to mac-ecosystem. I would appreciate any suggestions, where should one start.

Maybe some recommendation for a library to manipulate finder? Also does replacing files through terminal also requires authorization?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the icon for an application using the following python script without touching its icon file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import Cocoa,argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("target_file")
parser.add_argument("-image_file",required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

Cocoa.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(Cocoa.NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(args.image_file), args.target_file, 0)
```

usage: set_icon.py [-h] -image_file IMAGE_FILE your_app

Comment: Thank you for the script, mate. I've installed python, and created python file. Now I need to pass arguments, but don't really know how to do that. Can you provide me with an example of how to pass them?I would be super grateful :).

Comment: python set_icon.py -image_file new-icon.png my.app
(assuming your python file is called "set_icon.py")